# Using the decimal EditText to change Currency ?

Tags: java, android, numbers, toast

I am building a very simple currency converter app for a course I am doing.

The App has a decimal Edit text box where you enter the amount and when you press the button it will convert the amount from £ sterling to U.S dollars and gives the user the difference in a Toast message.

I need help with the java code for the currency conversion part , if anyone can help that will be much appreciated.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hydraquip_10.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/currency"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Result"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:onClick="changeCurrency"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Enter amount £"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

main java

```
package com.example.hydraquip_10.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void changeCurrency(View view){

        EditText changeNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Currency = $" + changeNumber.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your error exactly and what do you mean i need help with the java code? so untill now you just take the price of an edittext and just display it a toast?

Comment: Which is the part that is not working?

Comment: If someone enters say £1.50 it will bring that up in a toast message at the moment.. What I am, trying to do is, when the user puts in put £1.50 in and presses the button the app converts it into $ and displays it in a toast message.